# Call this.instanceMethod inside another instance method event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call instance method inside event handler of another instance method but I am getting function undefined, I assume this is because in the event handler "this" refers to  DOM element rather then the instance:

```
function MyObject(something) {
   this.something = something;
   this.value = 'abc';
}

MyObject.prototype.Init = function() {

  $(this.something).click(function() {
     this.DoSomething();
  });
};

MyObject.prototype.DoSomething = function() {
 //do something
};
```

Is there way to get "this" to point to instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define another variable whose name is something other than `this` and assign it the context you wish to refer to in your inner function:

```
MyObject.prototype.Init = function() {
  var scope = this;
  $(this.something).click(function() {
     scope.DoSomething();
  });
};
```